# Is a continuous function a continuous operator on the space of Hölder functions?

Tags: continuity, operator-theory, holder-spaces

Consider a continuous function $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $C^\alpha(A)$, the space of Hölder-continuous functions on a bounded set $A \subseteq \mathbb R$, and the induced function $F \colon C^\alpha(A) \to C^\alpha(A)$, $F(g) := f \circ g$.

**Question**: Can I, under any conditions or modifications which do not force $f$ to be an affine function, guarantee that $F$ will be continuous?

First, I directly tried to prove that $F$ is Lipschitz:
$$ \Vert F(g) - F(h) \Vert_{C^\alpha(A)} \le L\Vert g - h\Vert_{C^\alpha(A)}, $$
which would, in particular, imply
$$ \vert f(g(x)) - f(h(x)) - f(g(y)) + f(h(y))\vert \\
= \vert (F(g) - F(h))(x) - (F(g) - F(h))(y)\vert \\
\le L \Vert g - h\Vert_{C^\alpha(A)} \vert x - y\vert^\alpha,$$
but this seems to be not provable that because it seems impossible to split the sum into a product of $g - h$ and $x - y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This superposition operator, also known as (autonomous) [Nemytskii operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemytskii_operator), is continuous on Hölder spaces **if and only if $f$ is $C^1$-smooth**. This is Theorem 2 in

1. Pavel Drábek, *Continuity of Nemyckij's operator in Hölder spaces*, Commentationes Mathematicae Universitatis Carolinae, Vol. 16 (1975), No. 1, 37-57. [Available online](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/105604).

If you find this pre-TeX paper hard to read, there's a more general form of the same result in

2. Manfred Goebel, *Continuity and Fréchet-differentiability of Nemytskij operators in Hölder spaces*, Monatsh. Math. 113 (1992), no. 2, 107–119. [MR citation](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1154474).

Finally, there is a painfully detailed further study of this problem in section 7.4 of the book

3. Jürgen Appell and Petr P. Zabrejko, *Nonlinear superposition operators*. 
   Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics, 95. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1990. viii+311 pp. [MR citation](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1066204)